# Display complex JSON with use of jquery .each

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, each

I was having trouble trying to make this code work. I really don't see anything wrong with the javascript. When I debug, I don't find errors either.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#Presentation').click(function() {
var jsonloc = "ppt.json";
        $.when($.getJSON(jsonloc)).then(function(info){
        $('#header').empty();
            $.each(info.slides, function(entryIndex, entry){
            var html = '<div class="info">';                      
            html += '<h3>' + entry['title'] + '</h3>';
            html += '<div class="author">' + entry['author'] + '</div>';                    
                if(entry['slides']){
                    $.each(entry['slides'],function(slideIndex, slides){
                        html += '<h3>' + slides['Slide'] + '<h3>';                                          
                        html += '<div class="header">' + slides['header'] + '</div>';                          
                        }); 
                if(slides['Content']){
                html += '<div class="Content">';                                            
                html += '<ol>';
                    $.each(slides['content'],function(contentIndex, content){
                        html += '<li>' + content + '</li>';                        
                            }); 
                        html += '</ol>';                        
                        html += '</div>';                               
                    };                                  
                $('#header').append(html);
            };                         
        });
        return false;
    });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="Presentation">ppt presentation</a>
<div id="header">
</div>
</body>
```

here is the JSON:

```
{
    "title": "presentation",
    "date_created": "",
    "last_modified": "",
    "author": "By: Someone online",
    "slides": [
        {
            "Slide": "1",
            "header": "first header",
            "src": "ssss.jpg",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
        },
        {
            "Slide2": "2",
            "header2": "header 2",
            "src2": null,
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"

        },
        {
            "Slide3": "3",
            "header3": "header3",
            "src3": "sdfdsf.jpg",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
            "Content": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
        }
    ]
}
```

I really want to make this work and don't want to use other methods such as jquery templates. 
Is there anything that jumps out?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to have a `json` file with the same keys multiple times, because you won't be able to retrieve the value for Content`

Comment: I was trying different codes and methods. I have the JSON fixed now.

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant json

Answer (score 1):

You're closing `.each` too soon :

```
$.each(entry['slides'],function(slideIndex, slides){
    html += '<h3>' + slides['Slide'] + '<h3>';                                          
    html += '<div class="header">' + slides['header'] + '</div>';                          
 }); 
 if(slides['Content']){ 
 // ...
```

That way you only access the last value of `slides['Content']`.

You need to put that `if` and what it contains into your loop like this :

```
 $.each(entry['slides'],function(slideIndex, slides){
    html += '<h3>' + slides['Slide'] + '<h3>';                                          
    html += '<div class="header">' + slides['header'] + '</div>';      
    if(slides['Content']){
    // ...

 });
```

Comment: Okay, so I corrected that, but still... there is no JSON displayed

Comment: Also your `json` is messed up, why do you have "Slide", "Slide2", "Slide3" ?

Comment: I was trying other codes on the JSON so I kept changing it. Ive corrected it now, however, still no luck.